# Laravel model use default value instead of attribute value with the same name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a percentage discount to a product if an offer is created for an ecommerce store, although i would like to modify the table "sale" in products instead of creating a new attribute because this will save me a lot of time but I'm stuck because if i create a sale attribute to the model product i can't use the default sale value if a product doesn't have an offer, example below:

Inside product model file:

```
 public function getSaleAttribute() {

        $offer = $this->offer()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->active()->first();

        if($offer) {
            $sale = $this->price - ($this->price*$offer->percentage/100);
        }
        else {
            $sale = $this->sale;
        }
        

        return number_format($sale, 2);
        
    }
```

What happens is, I check if an offer which is active exists and place the value in the product sale table, if it does not exist use the default sale value. I'm getting an error `Undefined property: App\Product::$sale` and that is because i have created an attribute named the same, but as i mentioned earlier this will save me a lot of time and i don't want to make the attribute name different, is there anyway to surpass that and use the default sale value that is set in the product sale table if an offer does not exist?

Comment: Do note that you've built yourself a N+1 problem (that won't be solvable with eager loading as-written) that'll result in lots of database queries in some scenarios. "this will save me a lot of time" may be true in the short-run, but a year later it may waste hours/days of debugging because you forgot it works this way. I'd split up the base price and the current sale price into separate attributes for clarity, both for your future self and any potential other developers who may have to maintain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->getRawOriginal('sale')` ([API docs](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getRawOriginal)) will obtain the value of `sale` without any accessors getting in the way.